# How to uniquely identify a process

Tags: c#, process

I have a .net wpf application with exe name TestTool.

From a separate application I want to get hold of this process. I used to get the 
process using the process name. Code snipet below:

```
  var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestTool");
```

Now, my worry is, if there is some other exe running with the same name than I might
come accross a scenario where I get the wrong process.

Is there a way that I uniquely identify my TestTool process?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Linq to determine for sure if the process is running based on process exe file location, like this example:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Dns_management");

bool pIsRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("Dns_Management")
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(@"F:\VS_2015_WorkSpace\Projects\DNS_Management\DNS_Management\bin\Debug")) 
                != default(Process);

            if (pIsRunning == true)
            {
                foreach (Process p in process)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + " Is Running");
                }
                            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process is not available");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might check the filename:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("TestTool").MainModule.FileName;
```

Or you could do:

- a CRC check
- check the file's version information.
- check for an extra file in the same path